# Getting random data from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm fairly new to android so i have this functionality that needs to select a random record from my database so what i did was create a function in my dbhelper just like this

**updated function to select random records**

```
 public List<Restaurant> getSOMERESTAURANT()
{
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESTAURANT ,null);
    int cnt = c.getCount();
    //get total number of records in the database
    String offsetSize = "" + c.getCount();
    Log.d("Offset Size: " , offsetSize);

   //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESTAURANT + " LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + cnt;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RESTAURANT + " LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + cnt, null);

    //check if there was something selected
    String scnt = "" + cursor.getCount();
    Log.d("Size: " , scnt);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Restaurant rest = new Restaurant();
            rest.setrID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            rest.setArea(cursor.getString(1));
            rest.setRestaurant(cursor.getString(2));

            restaurants.add(rest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return restaurants;
}
```

i added logs to the total size in my database where i got correct data but when i use it to the search query for my random record the size it returned is 0 any idea on what is wrong with my select query?

then in my other java class im trying to see whether or not i am getting the random data here is the code that i have

```
Log.d("Reading: " , "RANDOM..");
        List<Restaurant> randome = db.getSOMERESTAURANT();
        for(Restaurant r : randome)
        {
            String rdata = r.getrID() + " " + r.getArea() + " " + r.getRestaurant();
            Log.d("Restaurants" , rdata);
        }
```

the thing is im not getting anything just the `Log.d("Reading: " , "RANDOM..");` no data afterwards. Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Check what is the size of `randome` list

Comment: Try to debug method "getSOMERESTAURANT()" .check selectQuery,while loop exiting conditions

Comment: hi i added the sizes to the log and the problem was on my select query for a random record any idea what my error is? thanks

Comment: @BourneShady First of all please close the first cursor as soon as you are done with it, as keeping cursor open is not good coding and it may be possible it can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OFFSET <count>` skips over all rows, and then there is no row left to return.

To get a random row, you would have to skip a random amount that is smaller than the number of rows.

But a single query that reorders the rows randomly, and then just takes the first, would be simpler:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: hi thanks i used this but i also read from some stacks that there is an issue about using random() like for big tabless. worked for me anyways. thanks!